# counting duplicates from two columns in a SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, count, group-by

I'm no SQL expert by any means so please excuse me if this is simplistic. I have a table that stores customer brand selections they can choose up to two brands.  I need to count the single brand entries and the combinations but I'm having trouble I need to look at the combination of a+b the same as b+a. So far I've got:

`SELECT DISTINCT brand, brand2, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY brand, brand2;`

This gets me this output from this table and "desired" is what I'm looking to get

```
     table                  output                        desired

brand | brand2|      brand | brand2| count(*)|    brand | brand2| count(*)|
  a   |   b   |        a   |   b   |     1   |      a   |   b   |     2   |
  b   |       |        b   |       |     2   |      b   |       |     2   |
  c   |   b   |        c   |   b   |     1   |      c   |   b   |     2   |
  b   |       |        b   |   a   |     1   |      e   |       |     1   |
  b   |   a   |        b   |   c   |     1   |
  b   |   c   |        e   |       |     1   |
  e   |       |
```

I hope this is clear I'm really just blocked here. Not to sure how I can get the output I need. I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: it's time like this that I wish I had normalised the database...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
    substring_index(concat_ws(',', `brand`, `brand2`), ',', 1) as `brand`,
    substring_index(concat_ws(',', `brand`, `brand2`), ',', -1) as `brand2`,
    count(*)
from yourtable
group by case when `brand` > `brand2` then concat(`brand`, `brand2`)
              else concat(`brand2`, `brand`) end
order by `brand`
```

[<kbd>SqlFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82ed0/4)

Comment: which rows show in the output seems to change randomly.  depending on the input ordering... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a02d81/3

Comment: @Jasen You're absolutely right. I only return one row for each group here, also the OP did not give us which one to reserve. And your answer is definitely right, it's great.

Answer (score 1):

here's a way that uses standard sql.

```
select
    case when brand >= brand2 and brand2 <>'' then brand2 else brand end as `brand`,
    case when brand >= brand2 and brand2 <>'' then brand else brand2 end as `brand2`,
    count(*)
from yourtable
group by 1,2               
order by 1,2
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82ed0/14)